# SparQL query returning LIKE results for id

Tags: sparql, rdf

SparQL query returns results you would expect in a SQL LIKE query as opposed to returning only the results that contain the identical ID

```
select distinct ?protein_id
where {
     ?protein_id a uniprot-voc:Protein
}
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: What is the actual database that you use?

Comment: not sure if I understand you, but all your query does is *"give me all Proteins"* resp. the URIs of the entities. If you have a specific ID, you should use this as subject (or as an additional triple pattern - I don't know how Uniprot is modelled.

Comment: If mean, getting data about a specific protein is simply done by using the URI and running `select * where {<https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q8CY28> ?p ?o }` - I don't know what is mena by containing an ID - isn'T an ID unique to something? Or is it some attribute of a protein shared among other proteins?